# type radio com nomes diferentes

Tags: html5

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para quando um radio estiver marcado o outro desmarque, mas os dois com nomes diferentes.

```html
<span style="text-shadow: 0 0 7px blue; color: white; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;">USA</span>
<input type="radio" id="usa" name="usa" value="usa">
<span style="text-shadow: 0 0 7px blue; color: white; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;">BRAZIL</span>
<input type="radio" id="brazil" name="brazil" value="brazil">
```

Comment: Se eles representam o mesmo tipo de dado e são mutuamente exclusivos, então eles deveriam ter o mesmo nome. Fazer diferente disso será gambiarra e não será recomendado.

Answer (score 0):

Não tem como, você tem que dar o mesmo nome pra cada, o nome é a categoria do item e não o valor, o valor é o que o PHP vai receber, tipo, você o que muda é o `value`.

Ou seja, `name` é categoria "Land" (País, origem, etc)
E o `value` é a seleção que o usuário fizer usuário/cliente.

Exemplo:

```html
<form onchange="alert('Seu país é '+this.pais.value+'\r\nForma de pagamento: '+this.pagamento.value)">
<p>Seu país atual:</p>
  <input type="radio" name="pais" value="BRASIL" checked>Brasil<br>
  <input type="radio" name="pais" value="URUGUAI">Uruguai<br>
  <input type="radio" name="pais" value="E.U.A">Estados Unidos da América<br>
<!-- Forma de pagamento -->
<p>Escolha sua forma de pagamento:</p>
  <input type="radio" name="pagamento" value="CREDCARD" checked>Cartão de Crédito<br>
  <input type="radio" name="pagamento" value="CHEQUE">Cheque nominal<br>
  <input type="radio" name="pagamento" value="BOLETO">Boleto<br>
</form>
```

Usado `Chebox`:

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="pais1" value="Brasil">Brasil<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="pais2" value="EUA">Estados Unidos da América<br>
</form>
```

Comment: Então por gentilezaz, reformule sua pergunta, pois foi o que eu entendi no pedido, se marcar um desmarca o outro.

Mesmo assim editarei a resposta e você entenderá que cada NAME de rádio é pra uma escolha, se quiser selecionar mais de um vai ter que usar `CHECKBOX`.

Comment: Na verdade eu gostaria que, cada radio fosse um post, por exemplo, se a pessoa seleciona brazil, o código faz toda a requisição que esta no if ($_POST['brazil']).

Comment: Desculpa, mas não tem muito sendo, já que o correto seria `if ($_POST['pais'] === 'brazil'){//tu é BR muleke}`

Comment: Desta maneira funcionou, porém não há uma maneira que possa impedir de marcar os dois ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Viu que eu editei a resposta? No primeiro exemplo eu expliquei que o uso do `name` **que faz justamente isso que você pediu agora**. Depois você disse que queria selecionar os dois e agora voltou a pedir pra impedir que selecione os dois... Eu gostaria que você reformulasse a pergunta principal e se possivel veja o TOUR: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour
E leia isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help

Fico no aguardo camarada